# Having trouble understanding the Pointer-System of Boundary conditions on a simulation code

Tags: c, simulation, boundary

Ηi, Im having some troubles understanding how boundary conditions are working on a simulation code (written mainly in c) integrating known equations for a certain box.

It's for Physics, although the question is mainly programming.

Let's say you got a grid `5x5` as for `r x z`

At `r=0, r=5` and `z=0, z=5` the code must have known functions for the integrating quantities. For a common simulation, the code is solving for density`rho`, pressure `P` and velocity `V`.

As it stands on page 53of [THIS](http://plutocode.ph.unito.it/userguide.pdf) document, if we want for the quantity to be `reversed/reflected` we follow this code

```
/* -- reflective boundary for r > 1 --*/
d->Vc[RHO][k][j][i] = d->Vc[RHO][k][2*JBEG - j - 1][i];
```

If we want `d density / d [grid quantity] = 0` to be zero, so the same value on the beginning of the box, the code would be

```
/* -- outflow boundary for r > 1 --*/
d->Vc[RHO][k][j][i] = d->Vc[RHO][k][JBEG][i];
```

If I want for the code to follow a certain derivative lets say

```
d density / d [grid quantity] = A*[g q]**2/2
```

or a known function

```
density = B*[g q]**2/2
```

how would I write the boundary condition using that system.

Comment: Even though it will be implemented in code, for now it's more of a physics (or possibly even math) problem, which is why I vote this as off-topic. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: ok I'm sry. Didn't know where to ask

Comment: You can explore the [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) to find which site should answer that.

Comment: What's a boundary condition?

Comment: The physics one is here:https://physics.stackexchange.com/.  I would suggest, however, that you might have better luck if there is a discussion group particularly for this package.  I am a physicist as well as a coder and I would need to read much of that pdf to be able to answer your question, which is quite a big ask considerring that you are 53 pages in.

Comment: @melpomene a boundary condition is part of a problem definition, often used in physics.  You define a problem you are trying to solve (what note will a guitar string make when you pluck it) which will include boundary conditions (the string is held at both ends, so neither of these ends can move).